# Register, Modules View in Eclipse IDE for Java?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I dont see how Register, Modules View work in Eclipse Debug View ?. I run a class and have breakpoints. I can see Variables Expressions but why dont Registers and Modules View work ?

Comment: Please be a bit more precise.  What language are you developing in?

Comment: Language used for development is JAVA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those views are for C/C++ development.  They're not for use with Java.  I don't know why they are installed with the base Eclipse SDK, rather than with the C/C++ development tools (the CDT).  I have used Eclipse for 10 years, developing Java, and I've never used those views.

Answer (score -1):

To view a particular view in Eclipse:

1. ALT + SHIFT + Q
2. Q
3. Then type the name of the view that you want to see.

Once you have the perspective looking the right way, you can save it by selecting **Window->Save Perspective As...**